# What are Nosql database and how they are different from R-databases

Tags: mongodb, hadoop, cassandra, bigdata, nosql

What are nosql databases?

Nosql database is a buzzword now a days, I searched there are lots of nosql database like: mongodb, hadoop, cassandra...

But still I dont understand how they are different from Relational databases.

Answer (score 2):

nosql databases are key,value storage that provides functionalities/features like replication,fault tolerance,eventual consistency.Relational database is transactional consistent and with primary,secondary indexes,well designed cost/rule based optimizers. 
However,nosql scales horizontally and it is hard to scale relational database.